# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile

Tags: java, spring-boot

Имеется небольшой проект на микросервисах.

Java 14

корневой pom.xml

```
<groupId>ru.booking</groupId>
<artifactId>booking</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.12</version>
    <relativePath/>       
</parent>
<modules>
    <!-- MicroService -->
    <module>authentication</module>
    <module>content-service</module>
    <module>common</module>
</modules>
```

модуль authentication pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>booking</artifactId>
    <groupId>ru.booking</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>authentication</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>authentication</name>
<description>Authentication MicroService</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>       
    <jwt.version>3.13.0</jwt.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.18</lombok.version>
    <open.api.version>1.5.4</open.api.version>
    <common.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</common.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.booking</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>${common.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>${jwt.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

модуль content-service pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>booking</artifactId>
    <groupId>ru.booking</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>content-service</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>content-service</name>
<description>Service MicroService</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>14</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>14</maven.compiler.target>       
    <lombok.version>1.18.18</lombok.version>
    <open.api.version>1.5.4</open.api.version>
    <common.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</common.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.booking</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>${common.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

модуль common - в этом модуле будут только всякие структуры данных (например enum)
pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>booking</artifactId>
    <groupId>ru.booking</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>common</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>common</name>
<description>common MicroService</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>14</java.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.18</lombok.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

запускаю
mvn clean install
и в модуле common получаю ошибку:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project common: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor (in unnamed
 module @0x202ae86f) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.processing to unnamed module @0x202ae86f ->
[Help 1]
```

От куда берется эта версия плагина plugin:3.8.1, если у меня везде указана версия 2.4.2

Comment: `2.4.2` это версия `org.springframework.boot : spring-boot-maven-plugin` , а  `3.8.1` это версия `org.apache.maven.plugins : maven-compiler-plugin`

Comment: это разные версии РАЗНЫХ ПЛАГИНОВ

Comment: сам `maven-compiler-plugin` используется по умолчанию и его версия зависит от версии maven, которую вы используете, если вы не указали в конфигурации другого(а вы этого не сделали)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Касательно разных версий

- `2.4.2` это версия `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin`
- а `3.8.1` это версия `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin`

это разные версии разных плагинов.

`maven-compiler-plugin` используется по умолчанию и его версия зависит от версии maven, которую вы используете, если вы не указали в конфигурации другого

И разные версии этих плагинов никак не относятся к вашей ошибке.

## Касательно ошибки

Насколько мне известно, это косяк самого Lombok
И насколько я знаю, его уже поправили.

Просто смените версию Lombok с `1.18.18` на `1.18.20`

```java
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
  <version>1.18.20</version>
</dependency>
```